# Issue with Async post in c#

Tags: c#, webclient

I have two post in my project, one is Async and second post is normal but dependent on post 1.

post 1 return "**success**" as string. what happens here if post2 responds before post 1 then it give error. so what i want to do is to wait until post 1 return "**success**" in his response.

I don't understand how to do this. please suggest. following are my post request.

**// post 1**

startAsync("https://www.example.com", webClient, sPostData);

**// post 2**  : this depends on above post 1. i want post 1 to be completed before this respond.

```
html = oClient.Post("https://example.com" + "?"+sPostParameter, "");
```

**New EDIT**

```
 private async void startAsync(string url, ExtendedWebClient oExtendedWebClient, string sParam)
    {

        await CreateMultipleTasksAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sParam);

    }

private async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync(string url, ExtendedWebClient oExtendedWebClient, string sParam)
        {

            try
            {
                Task<int> download1 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sParam);
                Task<int> download2 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sPostData);
                Task<int> download3 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sPostData);
                Task<int> download4 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sPostData); 
                Task<int> download5 = oExtendedWebClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oExtendedWebClient, sPostData);
                // Await each task.
                int length1 = await download1;
                int length2 = await download2;
                int length3 = await download3;
                int length4 = await download4;
                int length5 = await download5;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLog.createLog("ex.StackTrace = " + ex.StackTrace + " ex.tostring = " + ex.ToString());
            }
}

 async Task<int> ProcessURLAsync(string url, ExtendedWebClient oExtendedWebClient, string sParam)
        {
            byte[] PostData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sParam);

            var byteArray = await oExtendedWebClient.UploadDataTaskAsync(url, PostData);
            //DisplayResults(url, byteArray);
            return byteArray.Length;
        }
```

i use startAsync method like this
startAsync("https://www.example.com", webClient, sPostData);

here i want to wait untill this end execution

Comment: That's exactly what `await` does, it waits for the operation to complete.  How exactly is this failing?

Comment: hi devid, thanks for your consideration. It dont wait at await and go to execute next line

Comment: Can you show the complete code in which the calls above are expressed?

Comment: there are a method .
startAsync("https://www.example.com", webClient, sPostData); this method contains 5 async post as post 1

Comment: @Karan we need to see more of the code, how is the method declared and such... it is guessing now

Comment: @Karan: The code you're showing doesn't produce the behavior you're describing.  Instead of vaguely describing what the overall code looks like, show a complete (and minimal) example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: hi peter i have edited and copyed my methods. i call startAsync method from above and want wo wait untill async finish

Comment: hi devid i call following method like this from above.
startAsync("https://www.example.com", webClient, sPostData);

here i want to wait untill this end execution

Comment: Is this a console application?

Comment: this is window application.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the keyword `async` no other events will fire until the `async` has been completed.

What helped me get a good grasp on how this works is the MSDN Example [image: Async Example]

Full Link Disclosure [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This can done using [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your code woul look something like

```
Task<int> download1 = await oClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, 
              oWebClient, 
              sParam).ContinueWith(
                  downloadTask =>{

                      if (downloadTask.Result == "success"){
                          var html = oClient.Post(
                              "https://example.com" + "?" + sPostParameter,
                              "");
                      } else{
                          //wait
                      }
                  });
```

Answer (score -2):

Since i agree this should already work with awaiting download1 you can force to wait for the task result (since you declared it as a Task<**int**> by using (edited and corrected, sry):

Replace

```
Task<int> download1 = oClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oWebClient, sParam);
int length1 = await download1;
```

With

```
int length1 = await oClient.ProcessURLAsync(url, oWebClient, sParam).Result;
```

Alternatively you can force waiting by using:

```
Task.WaitAll(download1);
```

Greetings
Konstantin

Comment: @KoPoCabana: It's not corrected at all, this code is still calling `await` on a `.Result`.  Why invoke `.Result` at all if `await` is an option?  In general, using `.Result` should be done very carefully.